# npm install permanently hangs on vagrant box with nfs sync

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, nfs

I have a vagrant box that needs nodejs'. Any 'npm install' command hangs forever if I have the vagrant guest box(linux) in sync with the host(linux) by nfs. I can successfully run 'npm install' if I have the vagrant box sync to the host via rsync. But that is not a good solution.

using --no-bin-links provides no help.

Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated.

- vagrant 1.7.2
- node 0.10.36 / npm 1.4.28 (or same results with node 0.12.3 / npm 2.9.1)

Answer (score 1):

Add `nfs_udp: false` to `config.vm.synced_folder` after `type: "nfs"`

in your Vagrantfile